# How do I make an xhr soap request in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

How do I make an xhr request in Node.js? This is my js file:

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

var url="https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/server";

function soap() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/server/myLoginProcess");

    // build SOAP request   
    var sr =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
'<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'+
    'xmlns:ns1=https://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/server/'+
    'xmlns:xsd=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/'+
    'xmlns:SOAP-ENC=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'+
    'SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=http://schemas.xmlsoap-org/encoding/>'+
    '<SOAP-ENV:Body>'+
        '<ns1:ihLoginProcess>'+
            '<sEmail xsi:type="xsd:string">me@mail.de</sEmail>'+
            '<sPasswort xsi:type="xsd:string">password</sPasswort>'+
            '<sDeviceID xsi:type="xsd:string">00-14-22-01-23-45</sDeviceID>'+
        '</ns1:ihLoginProcess>'+
    '</SOAP-ENV:Body>'+
'</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
        {
            console.log("onreadystatechange ");
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    console.log("status 200");
                    console.log('done !');

                }
            }else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 1){
                console.log("readyState 1");
            }
        }
        // Send the POST request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;; charset="utf-8"');
        xmlhttp.send(sr);
        // send request
        // ...
}       
soap();
```

In the terminal I'm writing:
node myJSFile.js

The result is:

```
onreadystatechange
readyState 1
onreadystatechange
```

But it should be readyState 4 and the sr should be send to the server. As a result I should get back an XML-string.

Comment: If you're making SOAP requests, you might consider using a module on npm that is designed for these types of requests, such as [`soap`](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the first time I have to do something with node.js and SOAP and xhr requests. Could you please tell me, how  it looks like with the node-module soap? (I already installed the module soap and also tried the example in the link you provided. It says cannot call method 'MyFunction' of undefined.)

Comment: i do the same thing and  print data use xmlhttp.send(sr); nothing to print. my url  {"url" : "http://thfwsv3.touricoholidays.com/HotelFlow.svc/bas/"} {"soapAction url" : "http://tourico.com/webservices/hotelv3/IHotelFlow/SearchHotels"} and xml data will send. please help me guys